# autowiring webapplicationcotnext in my spring 3.2 tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, web-applications

Following the instructions [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework/), but i get the error unable to autowire WebApplicationContext.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("applicationContext-test.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AjaxTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext; //FAILS
```

But this compiles :

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

And I don't understand why.

**Edit**
It runs fine using maven, it was my editor intellij showing an incorrect auto compile message, a [bug in fact](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98019).

Comment: Could you provide the exception?

Comment: @null I did, unable to autowire WebApplicationContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test class should implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface:

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
           private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

            public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
                return applicationContext;
            }
            public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
                 this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
            }
      }
```

Spring will automatically inject the application context.

Comment: ok, isn't that what the @ContextConfiguration annotation is supposed to do - they don't show implementing that interface in the example or did I miss something ?

Comment: no, you don't need to do this in spring 3.2, show your exception with stacktrace

Comment: @hoaz ok, I think its a problem with my test  application context being unable to load

Comment: @hoaz actually this runs fine, its an intellij bug